# Регулярные выражения: найти числа в скобках

Tags: python, python-3.x, re

```
a = 'Nightmare City (lite) 2001 film (2000, 2005-2007) DVD'

search = re.findall(r'([\d+]{4})', a)
p = ','.join(search)

print(p)
==>
2001,2000,2005,2007
```

---

Как из названия фильма получить вывод дат в скобках 2000, 2008-2007
при любом варианте написания, вместе с "-"?
например
(2000)
(2005, 2008-2007)
(2008 - 2007)
(2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009)

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/bugA8A/2

Comment: А без скобок как? просто цифры 2000, 2008-2007, ну искало в скобках а выводило без них

Comment: убирайте скобки кодом и не морочайтесь. или сделайте захватывающую группу в шаблоне (просто возьмите то, что надо в скобки) и  используйте певврую группу из результата

Comment: хорошо, спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Можно задачу разбить на две подзадачи: сначала найти нужную подстроку в скобках, а затем уже вытащить из неё нужные числа.

```
import re

a = 'Nightmare City (lite) 2001 film (2000, 2005-2007) DVD'

search = re.findall(r'(?<=\()\d{4}.*(?=\))', a)
result = re.findall(r'\d{4}', search[0])

p = ', '.join(result)
print(p)

------------------------------

2000, 2005, 2007
```